# Arbitrary fault abstraction in 'Reliable and Secure Distributed Programming'

Tags: distributed-systems, books

In the book by Cachin, Guerraoui, Rodrigues they discuss an arbitrary fault abstraction. It seems to me that this abstraction does not include crashes in its behavior. I think this because they propose an algorithm as follows:

- Send all messages infinite times.
- Keep a list of received messages in volatile memory, and only pass non-duplicates to the application level.
- Use message authentication codes for verification.

This means all sent messages are delivered exactly once within the system (given a non-zero chance of transmission between nodes). However this fails on a crash as volatile memory will be lost and duplicate messages will be passed to the application.

Is this correct?

Sorry for the book specific question.

Thank you.